# Error to install external module in Odoo 12

Tags: odoo

I am trying to install OCA external department module on Odoo 12 with demo data. When in the applications menu I select this module and click on the install button, I receive the following error. Sorry for my english. I have the latest version of python installed.

```
   Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-61>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 445, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 421, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 179, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\module.py", line 368, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\module.py", line 82, in load_module
    exec(open(modfile, 'rb').read(), new_mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\external_addons\crm_department\crm.py", line 23, in <module>
    from openerp.osv import orm, fields
ImportError: cannot import name 'fields'
```

Comment: Most lickly you are installing a wrong version

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install a module [crm_department](https://github.com/OCA/department/tree/8.0/crm_department) from OCA v8 in odoo v12 where the use of the `openerp.osv` is deprecated. you should migrate the module code to v12 using [the new API](https://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) then you will be able to install the module.